# Number of N-digit perfect squares and all its members

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, natural-numbers

I've been thinking about this for a few days, and I was wondering if there are resources out there that describes this? here is what I have so far.

$$ \text{Let}\; \mathbb{N} \;\text{be the set of Natural numbers} \; = \{1,2,3,4,..,N\},$$
Then there exists a set $\mathbb{S}$, such that for 
$$ s\in\mathbb{S}\; ;\; s_i = \{10^{i-1},...,(10^i-1)\} \;, \text{for} \; i = 1,2,3,...,M.  $$
     Example : $$s_1 = \{1,2,3,...,9\}\; ; \;\;\; i=1 = 1\;\text{digit}$$
     $$ s_2 = \{10,11,12,...,99\}\; ; \;\; i=2 = 2\;\text{digits} $$
     $$ s_3 = \{100,101,102,...,999\}\; ; \;\; i=3 = 3\;\text{digits} $$
     $$ ... $$
     $$ s_i = \{10^{i-1},...,(10^i - 1)\} ; \;\; i\; \text{digits} $$

Within each set $s_i$, there exists a set $\mathbb{A} $ such that for all members of $\mathbb{A}$, call it $a_p$, when squared are still a member of  $s_i$:  $$a\in\mathbb{A}\; ; \;\; a = \{ a_1,a_2,...,a_k \} $$ 
     $$(a_p)^2 \in s_i  ,\; \text{for}\; p = 1\; \text{to}\; k$$

Example :
     $$s_1 = \{1,2,3,...,9\}\; ; \;\;\; a_1 = \{1,2,3\}$$
     $$ s_2 = \{10,11,12,...,99\}\; ; \;\; a_2 = \{ a_1 , 4, 5,6,...,9\} = \{1,2,3 , 4, 5,6,...,9\} $$

I'm going to start omit the previous sets before the current $i^{th}$ set we're looking at. So it'll look like this:

$$s_2 = \{10,11,12,...,99\}\; ; \;\; a_2 = \{4, 5,6,...,9\}, $$

but also know that all previous sets before the current $i^{th}$ can included, but is not unique to the $i^{th}$ digits.

I'm going to list a few in the long version, just as an example. 
$$ s_3 = \{100,101,102,...,999\}\; ; \;\; a_3 = \{10,11,12,...,31 \}$$
$$ s_4 = \{1000,1002,1003,...,9999\}\; ; \;\; a_4 = \{32,33,34,...,99 \}$$
$$ s_5 = \{10000,...,99999\}\; ; \;\; a_5 = \{100,...,316 \} $$
$$ s_6 = \{100000,...,999999\}\; ; \;\; a_6 = \{317,...,999 \} $$
$$ s_7 = \{1000000,...,9999999\}\; ; \;\; a_7 = \{1000,...,3162 \} $$

Now we can write these compactly as, the first i=1,2,3 are written in the long way and i > 4 is written in the short hand version as given by $s_i$: 
$$s_1 = \{10^0,2,3,...,9\}\; ; \; a_1 = \{1,2,3\}\; ; \; t_1 = 3$$
$$s_2 = \{10^1,...,99\}\; ; \; a_2 = \{4, 5,6,...,9\}\; ; \; t_2 =  6 $$
$$s_3= \{10^2,...,999\}\; ; \; a_3 = \{10^1,...,31\}\; ; \; t_3 = 22 $$
$$s_4= \{10^3,...,(10^4 -1)\}\; ; \; a_4 = \{32,...,99\}\; ; \; t_4 = 68$$
$$s_5= \{10^4,...,(10^5 -1)\}\; ; \; a_5 = \{10^2,...,316\}\; ; \; t_5 = 217$$

I also introduced $t_i$, which is the count of the number of members of $a_i$, (this is exactly what you're solving for, I believe). Notice, we can get an exact solution for $t_i$ given by:
$$ t_i = (\{a_i\}_{max} - \{a_i\}_{min}) + 1 $$
(I think this could be calculated using a norm)

I'm going to list out a few sequences and point out an interesting patterns.

Starting with  $i=3$, (you could extend this to $i=1$ if you want),

if $i = odd$ : 
   The lower bound of $a_i$, call this $\{a_i\}_{min}$ is exactly $10^l$, where $l = (i-1)/2$ ;

if $i = even$ :
    The upper bound of $a_i$, call this $\{a_i\}_{max}$ is exactly $10^z - 1$, where $z = (i)/2$ ;

I claim that for $i=even$, you have

$$ s_{i-1} = \{10^{i-2},...,(10^{i-1}-1)\}\; ; \;\; a_{i-1} =\{10^l,...,upper\;bound_{(i-1)}\} \; ; \; t_{i-1} = ?   $$
$$ s_{i} = \{10^{i-1},...,(10^{i}-1)\}\; ; \;\; a_{i}  =\{lower\; bound_{(i)},...,(10^z-1)\} \; ; \; t_{i} = ?.$$

I'm still working/thinking about I can get the upper bounds, lower bounds, and $t_i$.

Here are the first 16 digits, and their lists. I also have done this out until 34 digits, took my computer a good few hours to compute by brute force. I am almost done with an algorithm that can do it much quicker.

Also note, that if you know the lower bounds and upper bounds, you can easily obtain $t$, which is the number of elements that are contained in $\{a_i\}$, since $\{a_i\}$ is ordered.

$$s_1 = \{10^0,2,3,...,9\}\; ; \; a_1 = \{1,2,3\}\; ; \; t_1 = 3$$
$$s_2 = \{10^1,...,99\}\; ; \; a_2 = \{4, 5,6,...,9\}\; ; \; t_2 =  6 $$
$$ s_3= \{10^2,...,999\}\; ; \; a_3 = \{10^1,...,31\}\; ; \; t_3 = 22 $$
$$ s_4= \{10^3,...,(10^4 -1)\}\; ; \; a_4 = \{32,...,99\}\; ; \; t_4 = 68$$
$$ s_5= \{10^4,...,(10^5 -1)\}\; ; \; a_5 = \{10^2,...,316\}\; ; \; t_5 = 217$$
$$ s_6= \{10^5,...,(10^6 -1)\}\; ; \; a_6 = \{317,...,999\}\; ; \; t_6 =  683$$
$$ s_7= \{10^6,...,(10^7 -1)\}\; ; \; a_7 = \{10^3,...,3162\}\; ; \; t_7 = 2163$$
$$ s_8= \{10^7,...,(10^8 -1)\}\; ; \; a_8 = \{3163,...,9999\}\; ; \; t_8 = 6837$$
$$ s_9= \{10^8,...,(10^9 -1)\}\; ; \; a_9 = \{10^4,...,31622\}\; ; \; t_9 =21623$$
$$ s_{10}= \{10^9,...,(10^{10} -1)\}\; ; \;\; a_{10} = \{31623,...,(10^5-1)\}\; ; \; t_{10} = 68377$$
$$ s_{11}= \{10^{10},...,(10^{11} -1)\}\; ; \;\; a_{11} = \{10^5,...,316227\} \; ; \; t_{11} = 216228$$ 
$$ s_{12}= \{10^{11},...,(10^{12} -1)\}\; ; \;\; a_{12} = \{316228,...,(10^6-1)\}\; ; \; t_{12} = 683772$$
$$ s_{13}= \{10^{12},...,(10^{13} -1)\}\; ; \;\; a_{13} = \{10^6,...,3162277\}\; ; \; t_{13} = 2162278$$
$$ s_{14}= \{10^{13},...,(10^{14} -1)\}\; ; \;\; a_{14} = \{3162278,...,(10^7-1)\} \; ; \; t_{14} = 6837722$$. 
$$ s_{15}= \{10^{14},...,(10^{15} -1)\}\; ; \;\; a_{15} = \{10^7,...,31622776\} \; ; \; t_{15} = 21622777$$
$$ s_{16}= \{10^{15},...,(10^{16} -1)\}\; ; \;\; a_{16} = \{31622777,...,(10^8-1)\} \; ; \; t_{16} = 68377223$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit unclear on what exactly you're asking, but my best guess is that the answer your looking for is summarised by

> All natural numbers between $10^n$ and $10^n\cdot\sqrt{10}$ squares to a number with $2n+1$ digits, and all natural numbers between $10^n\cdot\sqrt{10}$ and $10^{n+1}$ squares to a number with $2n+2$ digits.

Comment: Interesting, maybe I should revise it to all positive integers instead of all natural number? on the very first line.

Comment: If I change the wording from natural number to positive integers, is there a theorem/relationship that can essentially predict what you wrote in the yellow box?

Comment: Where can I read the proof of what you stated?

Comment: @ALam It's rather easy to prove: take an integer $x$ with $10^n\leq x<10^n\cdot\sqrt{10}$. Now square everything. What do you get? What does that say about the number of digits of $x^2$? Then do the other interval.

Comment: how can you get how many members are within that set?

Comment: @ALam Given two integers $m<n$, how can one in general to how many integers are between them? It's a rather simple operation.

Comment: True, but the bounds that are given by $10^n\cdot \sqrt{10}$ are not integers?

Comment: @ALam True. But correcting that is rather easy: there is an integer $k$ is such that "the integer $x$ lies between $10^n$ and $10^n\cdot\sqrt{10}$" means the same as "the integer $x$ lies between $10^n$ and $k$". Finding that integer is quite easy, actually. I can see that you have already done so several times for different $n$ in your question post.